# Python pandas read_csv merge every two columns and read them as a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Beginner in python and pandas and trying to figure out how to read from csv in a particular way.

My datafile

```
01 AAA1234 AAA32452 AAA123123 0 -9 C C A A T G A G .......
01 AAA1334 AAA12452 AAA125123 1 -9 C A T G T G T G .......
...
...
...
```

So I have 100.000 columns in this file and I want to merge every two columns into one. But the merging needs to occur after the first 6 columns. I would prefer to do this while reading the file if possible instead of manipulating this huge datafile/

Desired outcome

```
01 AAA1234 AAA32452 AAA123123 0 -9 CC AA TG AG .......
01 AAA1334 AAA12452 AAA125123 1 -9 CA TG TG TG .......
...
...
...
```

That will result in a dataframe with half the columns. My datafile has no col names, the names reside in a different csv but that is another subject.

I d appreciate a solution, thanks in advance!

Comment: use `read_fwf` with specific column widths?

Comment: Will check it thanks

Comment: While read_fwf seems the logical solution the problem is that my first 6 column values are not fixed width which causes a problem for the rest. But I think i m gonna work with read_fwf and experiment. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

Separate the data frame initially. I created one for experimental purposes:

[image]

Then I defined a function. Then passed in the dataframe which needed manipulation as an argument into the function

```
def columns_joiner(data):
    new_data = pd.DataFrame()
    for i in range(0,11,2): # You can change range to your wish
    # Here, I had only 10 columns to concatenate (Therefore the range ends at 11)
        ser = data[i] + data[i + 1]
        new_data = pd.concat([new_data, ser], axis = 1)

  return new_data
```

I don't think this is an efficient solution. But it worked for me.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but I specifiaclly asked if this could be dont through the read_csv params not after the dataframe is loaded into memory.